# Input type="time" how can i set time locale?

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem with that tag. I used Ionic framework.

And when I choose time, on some devices it's working well, but on Samsung S4, PM or AM is added in the input.

How can I choose locale for input time?

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that no code is in your request, its hard to answer this question, but from what u tell this might solve your issue:

```
<div class="col">
{{request.time | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'}} 
</div>
```

About dateTime formatting HH:mm should return a 24h clock hh:mm should return a 12h clock